# Raspberry Pi disconnects from network

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet-port

I have installed Raspbian and have attached 2TB External Hard Disk via USB with ext4 partition. I am trying to use it as a NAS device. Also I am accessing Pi over SSH from LAN and also from Internet. When I am accessing over Internet it gets disconnected randomly, lights on the board keep on blinking. It is not shown in connected devices list on my router Netgear (wnr2000v3). I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

First I had connected via Ethernet and I have also tried using WiFi card but the case is same.

Comment: Maybe a power issue? Is your hard drive also receiving its power from its own adapter or an expertnally powered usb-hub? Running low on power can result in some awkward behavior rather than shutting down the pi entirely. (As far as I know, the wired network connection is hardwired in as a usb device.)

Comment: USB drive have its own external adapter power supply.

Comment: can you test your power suply ? (http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/11/testing-raspberry-pis-power-supply.html)

Comment: I have the same issue. It's wired connected to my router and the LEDs stay on but I can no longer login to it with SSH. I run it headless.

Comment: I may have solved the issue, as stated by @RenéWolferink it was a power issue, I was using 5v 700mA adapter rather it should be 5v 1200mA.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was using 5v 1000mA and it kept losing the connection. Switched to 5v 2100mA and all is well.

Comment: I keep getting random disconnects from my network with `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`. I have a official Raspberry Pi USB-C Power Supply with these specs: AC 100-240V 50/60Hz input - DC 5.1V 3A output - 15.3W maximum output power. Is this enough power, or should I buy a new stronger one? If so, which one would you recommend?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 4 by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the answers given in the comments section (and get rid of another unanswered question):

Network disconnects were traced back to power supply issues. So beware of power brown-outs.

> - 5v 700mA adapter -> solution: 5v 1200mA adapter
> - 5v 1000mA adapter -> solution: 5v 2100mA adapter

Edit to add:

Here are some measurements regarding the power consumption of the various models of the Pi:

- https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-dramble/wiki/Power-Consumption
- http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi2-power-and-performance-measurement

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, using a 700 mA power supply. Power reqirements depend on what peripherals are connected. This [power supply](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply) page concludes that using a 1200mA power supply from a reputable retailer will provide ample power to run the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Thank you for your input and hope to see you around.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a Raspberry Pi 4 w/ 7" touch display, powered via PoE HAT. My SSH sessions would disconnect, leaving the SSH (sshd) process still running on the RPi, leaving me to believe it was a hardware or power issue.

Disabling the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth radios using the hardware overlay system in Raspbian, edit /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

Seems to allow the RPi to operate without issues. The touch screen and RPi work fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my LAN disconnection issues after battling for months.

> sudo ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off