# What causes Raspberry Pi to reliably drop SSH connections: `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

Tags: networking, ssh

### The Issue:

SSH connections from a Macbook (Catalina - **the SSH Client**) to an RPi 4B (Buster, Linux v 4.19.97-v7l+ - **the SSH Server**) are *reliably dropped* at random times, but SSH connections from the same Macbook to an Ubuntu Server (18.04 LTS - **another SSH Server**) are never (hardly ever) dropped. For this reason, I think the cause is the RPi, and not the Macbook, but I am keeping an open mind. I am trying to understand the cause for this, but **the *primary* question here is how to prevent the SSH disconnects**.

- The error message is always: **`client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`**
- The disconnects happen when the Macbook's lid is open, and when it's closed.
- The disconnects happen with 3B and 1BP RPis also, but my question is only for the 4B.

Here's the *setup*:

#### 1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for Ubuntu & RPi are virtually identical; diffs are:

> For the Ubuntu Server:
> #  $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $
> Line 96:    #UseLogin no
> Line 123:   PasswordAuthentication yes

> For RPi 4B, sshd_config is default (as I found it) :
> #  $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

#### 2. Login/Authentication:

- Ubuntu logins are done w/ userid & password;
- RPi logins are done w/ stored SSH credentials.

#### 3. Network Connection & Provisioning:

- Both RPI and Ubuntu are connected to the LAN via Ethernet.
- Ubuntu Server has a fixed IP, RPi 4B uses DHCP.
- Macbook connects to the **same LAN** as the servers, uses **same DHCP server**, but is connected via WiFi

#### 4. SSH versions:

- Macbook:

  ```
  % ssh -V
  OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
  ```
- Ubuntu:

  ```bsh
  $ ssh -V
  OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
  ```
- Raspberry Pi 4B:

  ```bsh
  $ ssh -V  
  OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
  ```

#### 5. Keep-Alive Arrangements:

I've tried numerous settings on both the client-side (ssh), and the server-side (sshd). The results have been the same: RPi connections reliably drop at random times, Ubuntu Server connections never (hardly ever) drop. I finally decided to use default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files on all SSH servers, and deal with Keep-Alive in the (Macbook) SSH client. Here's what I've got now:

```
% cat .ssh/config
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

> **ServerAliveInterval**
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server.

As of 2021-04-25, the Mac's client configuration at `~/.ssh/config` is:

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ServerAliveInterval 6000
    ServerAliveCountMax 240
    TCPKeepAlive no
```

#### 6. Is it a Power Issue?

I don't think it's a [power issue as discussed here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5429/raspberry-pi-disconnects-from-network) for three (3) reasons:

- I'm using a 5V, 3A USB-C Power Supply mfd by Apple w/ a non-eMarked cable.
- The Power Supply is plugged into a massive UPS that's lightly loaded. The UPS log shows no issues for weeks on end.
- I have 2 other Raspberry Pis: a 1BP (*buster*), and a 3B (*stretch*) that reliably but randomly drop SSH connections just as the 4B does.

#### 7. Is it a Macbook Issue?

Obviously I don't think so, or I'd post the question somewhere else. If the Macbook sits for a while, the connection will drop

But those of you familiar with Apple's myriad schemes for power saving may suspect that is the most likely cause. I thought so too initially, but as I've experimented w/ this, I've come to feel it's *more likely* a Raspberry Pi issue. ICYI, a s/s of the Macbook (SSH Client) Power Management settings is shown below. There's also a power management mode called [**standby**](https://www.howtogeek.com/260478/how-to-choose-when-your-mac-hibernates-or-enters-standby/) that has been disabled (i.e. never go into *standby*) and confirmed as follows:

```
% sudo pmset -a standby 0 
% pmset -g | grep standby
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              0          # no standby confirmed
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 highstandbythreshold 50
```

[image: Energy Saver config - macOS Catalina]

Comment: I'm just looking at a similar issue with my RasPi using Buster. It does not disconnect completely but after a time it does not prompt immediately when hitting enter. It takes some time. Maybe it's the same reason? Try to decrease ServerAliveInterval maybe down to 15. Test ssh from the Ubuntu server to the RasPi.

Comment: From my Mac (Mojave) I get the same error after the Mac goes to sleep + I see the WiFi connection acting oddly - it can reach internal addresses but not any external ones!  It's possible the System Settings / Energy Saver / Power Nap needs ticking.  I'm just building a 64Bit x86 linux box and will try this in the next day or so...

Comment: With my Mac awake and active, the ssh connection has stayed up nearly two hours so far - this is with the terminal shell to the Pi minimised.  The Mac was being used for all sorts during this time AND I had Amphetamine running.  The Pi is a Pi 3B running Buster.  I'll let the Mac go to sleep and see what happens - I've one session to the Pi and one to an Ubuntu server running.

Comment: @Ingo: I'll try changing the ServerAliveInterval. Wrt ssh from Ubuntu to RPi: I did that. It works, but when RPi disconnects, so does Ubuntu connection. I think what I need to properly test is two connections to Ubuntu: one to RPi, and one just to Macbook. Any thoughts on a method to log these "Keep Alive" messages? I don't even know the source of the disconnect error message... Server or Client?

Comment: @Andyroo: Yeah - I'm pretty sure that Sleep = No WiFi. I've played around with the power settings in the GUI, but nothing seems to help. There are LOTS more options in `pmset`, but documentation is poor. In fact, it's difficult to tell what happens in any of these modes - seems Apple changes them at their whim & can't be bothered to document anything. (Yes, I am currently unhappy with several of Apple's decisions.)

Comment: I would try with `ssh -vvv -o ServerAliveInterval=30 pi@<raspi-ip>`. There you have extended logging (-vvv) and a simple way to fiddle with ServerAliveInterval. I think the disconnect error message is from the client when the server cuts the session.

Comment: And yes, if nothing goes, tcpdump is your friend.

Comment: @Ingo: Good suggestions - a few comments follow: 1.) To which logfile does this `-vvv` go?      2.) Will this logging record "KeepAlive" msgs from the client, and the Server's replies?    3.) I am also considering the `ServerAliveCountMax` option because I have also noticed occasional long delays in responses from the RPi SSH Server.      Finally - assuming we find RPi SSH Server is not responding to keep-alives, what on earth to do about that?

Comment: To increase the loglevel for sshd (server) set `loglevel` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `DEBUG[1..3]`; see `man sshd_config`. 1.) Output of the -vvv option on the ssh client goes to the console. You can redirect it into a file as usual with `>` operator, e.g. `ssh ... > ssh.log` or if you like to see what happens, pipe it to `tee` like `ssh ... | tee ssh.log`. 2.) Don't know if you see the "KeepAllive" with the extended logging. In any case you should find them with tcpdump (or they are already encrypted?).

Comment: What to do on earth? We have to find the reason: handshake failure, lost packets, interrupted line/hardware connection, wrong protocol handling ...

Comment: Running the same job tonight without the console output (using tmux on the Ubuntu box) to see if both boxes stay connected.  Mac still awake via Internet sharing :-o

Comment: @Ingo: Briefly, I've followed your suggestion re `ssh -vvv ...` : Good News: The output is all to `stderr`, but after a short period, the following pair of messages repeat at regular intervals: `debug3: send packet: type 80`; `debug3: receive packet: type 82`. Bad News: This output stops shortly after closing the lid on Macbook! I should log this from the Pi. Continue this in chat?

Comment: I have just no idea what type 80 and type 82 mean. With chat wait until it is presented here, because of direct reference to this discussion.

Comment: @Ingo: Based on the timing (I watched for a while with a stop watch :) I am guessing these are the "keep-alive" messages from the client to the server & the server's reply.  However, I've not been able to find *anything* that documents what these packet types are! I'm wondering now what is the best host to monitor the traffic - or if both hosts should be monitored? --- Still not getting a prompt to move this to chat??

Comment: No, don't get an invitation for a chat up to now. What's about the connection between RasPi and Ubuntu server as suggested in my first comment? Is it stable?

Comment: I only tested that once, but it dropped the connection rather quickly which then dropped the SSH connection to my Mac; i.e. mac=ssh=>ubuntu=ssh=>RPi. It's just now occurred to me that this may not have been what you meant in your suggestion??

Answer (score 3):

**Sorry to say I think this is a Mac issue and not a Pi issue.**

I set up this for a test yesterday:

Pi <==> Ethernet to Router <==> Mains network <==> Airport 5Ghz <==> Mac terminal

x86 Ubuntu server Ethernet <==> Mac terminal (i.e. directly connected)

Running `ifconfig` on the Pi box gives me:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether b8:27:eb:15:ce:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Running `ifconfig` on the Ubuntu box gives me:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet6 fe80::230:1bff:febf:eca4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
```

Note the PI is IPv4 only, where as the Ubuntu box is IPv4 and IPv6

Connection to Ubuntu via IPv6 - Connection to PI via IPv4 - Internet sharing set on for Ubuntu link to stop the Mac going to sleep though screen saver set for 10 mins and sleep set for 45 mins.  Sharing Internet overrides sleep mode.

Pi not doing anything but sitting at the command line
Ubuntu copying nearly 3TB of data (1000s of files) via `rsync -v` - so lots and lots of text coming out on to the terminal session

Came back just now (just got up) to the Ubuntu linked shell showing:

> packet_write_wait: Connection to fe80::230:1bff:febf:eca4%bridge100 port 22: Broken pipe

So the Mac is reporting the drop to the x86 box while **the Pi connection was still solid and active**.

So it is a possible overrun issue somewhere in the Terminal program / shell or network stack on the Apple - I often see the fail after lots and lots of text has been output (I'm moving *thousands* of archived pictures, files and TimeMachine backups around at the mo sorting out old 2014-2016 archives).

I have now seen this on both IPv6 and IPv4 connections BUT not seen it in remote TimeMachine backups.

A very quick trawl though the Mac system logs only shows Terminal starting so that's not a lot of help (TBH I'm not great at Mac debugging - not a lot of issues on it so could have missed something.)

Comment: Ran the same task overnight to just now again but with output going to a disconnected tmux session - both the Pi and the Ubuntu box stayed up fine. Convinced its a Mac issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now agree with your opening assertion, *"I think this is a Mac issue and not a Pi issue"* (+1), **BUT:** I don't feel the rest of your answer re causation is totally relevant. I've discovered some information and seen enough now to convince me that your opening assertion is correct, but **"the answer"** seems to lie in some arcane settings in macOS. I'll post something like an answer within the next day or two - even though this now seems "off-topic" for Raspberry Pi SE.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has persisted with Big Sur. In hunting around, the solution may be to add/edit to your ~/.ssh/config file on your Mac the following:

TCPKeepAlive no

The reasoning for and source of this proposed answer can be found here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602518/ssh-connection-client-loop-send-disconnect-broken-pipe-or-connection-reset

Quoting from that source:

> TCPKeepAlive no means "do not send keepalive messages to the server".
> When the opposite, TCPKeepAlive yes, is set, then the client sends
> keepalive messages to the server and requires a response in order to
> maintain its end of the connection. This will detect if the server
> goes down, reboots, etc. The trouble with this is that if the
> connection between the client and server is broken for a brief period
> of time (due to flaky a network connection), this will cause the
> keepalive messages to fail, and the client will end the connection
> with "broken pipe".
>
> Setting TCPKeepAlive no tells the client to just assume the connection
> is still good until proven otherwise by a user request, meaning that
> temporary connection breakages while your ssh term is sitting idle in
> the background won't kill the connection.

Comment: The explanation sounds reasonable (+1), and definitely worth a try. I've just added a comment confirming my "non-answer" hasn't actually made any difference. I'll let you know if your suggestion helps. And BTW - you are still very much in the running for "The Accepted Answer", **but** you should structure your answer in the form of a recommended `~/.ssh/config` file, and indicate what your results have been.

Comment: LOL... yeah, the "comment box" uses a different set of Markdown rules - it kinda' sucks  :)  As far as the "original answerer": don't worry about him - he no longer has an account here (note the pale user handle & no 'popup' when hovering over it). He ***may have*** been correct that it's a Mac issue, ***BUT*** the connection drops even when I launch SSH connection under `caffeinate` which according to Apple prevents sleep. Do you use a Mac?

Comment: Oh - one other thing re the comment boxes: Notifications. When I post a comment to your answer, you're notified because it's **your** post. However, if you reply to my comment, I may not get a notification unless you put my handle at the beginning of your reply; i.e. "@seamus blah, blah...". I think this is documented *somewhere*, but can't find it now.

Comment: Ooops... better late than never, I hope. To finally follow up, I've made the change you suggested, and tested this on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.6). Unfortunately, it does not cure the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I never made much progress trying to chase this down to determine the "root cause". However, for reasons unknown to me, the number of dropped SSH connections has decreased to near zero. The SSH software hasn't changed since I posted the question about 4 months ago... as of today:

RPi4B:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

macOS:

```
% ssh -V                                                        
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Of course there have been updates to both systems since the question was posted. Perhaps something in the networking stacks of one or both OS? At this point it seems unlikely a definitive answer will emerge, but I'll leave this open for a while longer before "closing" it with acceptance of an answer.

Comment: Update: Since posting this "non-answer" reporting the frequency of dropped connections had abated, the trend reversed itself, and SSH connections drop reliably. I've tried launching the SSH connections under Mac's `caffeinate`, but it seems to have no effect. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be a Router issue.  I was using dd-wrt and had to disable "Shortcut Forwarding Engine" in the Setup page.

Comment: Appreciate the thought, but I don't use `dd-wrt` for a router - I use an OPNsense firewall/router/DHCP server/etc/etc, and it has no *shortcut forwarding engine*. Are you using a Mac client also?

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that I experience a similar issue still on a
rPI 4B with rasbian/debian 11 (bullseye).

My setup is a Rpi connected to ethernet (via powerline) then to a router/modem. And my laptop (debian testing / bookworm) via wifi to the same router.

SSH sessions randomly close with an error

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Also many times I have to try 2 or 3 times to connect on the rpi, since I get this error without even getting a terminal

Connection reset by 192.168.2.130 port 22

As a workaroung I also installed tellnetd on the rpi and honestly it feels strange to use telnet after all, but it works ! I mean I have simultaneous connections from my laptop to rpi with ssh and telnet, and while the first one dies randomly with client loop... the other is not affected!

I used to have the debian 11 ssh version 1:8.4p1-5+deb11u1 still having the issue. Then upgraded to testing version 1:9.0p1-1+b2 and still have the issue.
So for server it is

```
sshd -V OpenSSH_9.0p1 Debian-1+b2, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
```

and for the client

```
ssh -V OpenSSH_9.0p1 Debian-1+b2, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
```

SSH versions on server(rpi)

I have also tried to disable TCPKeepAlive both on client and server to no avail.

**edit** It seems that the problem is caused by the router somehow emiting RST packets in one way of the TCP stream, thus breaking the connection. It this case I could verify that the other end (on the rPI ssh server) has still an ESTABLISHED tcp connection that does not exist on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

## My solution steps to reproduce:

1. be sure you are connected on internet so download and install `Raspberry Pi Imager` from official https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/
2. so from your `macOS` open up `Raspberry Pi Imager`
3. at operating system choose `Erase Format card as FAT32`. So choose `Storage` and then `Write`
4. at operating system choose `Raspberry Pi OS (other)` then choose `Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32-bit)`. So choose `Storage` and then `Write`
5. to let `ssh` available into `raspberrypi` just create an empty file called `ssh` into `/Volumes/boot`
6. you can now safely disconnect `/Volumes/boot`
7. power-on via `ethernet` this `raspberrypi` with the new `boot`
8. be sure on your `macOS` file `~/.ssh/config` is empty
9. be sure on your `macOS` file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is empty
10. from your `macOS` open up a terminal and run command `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` so choose `yes` and type default password `raspberry`
11. get `ip` of `raspberrypi` by running command `hostname -I`
12. run command `exit`
13. now use command `ssh pi@<ip address you copied just above>` so choose `yes` and type default password `raspberry`
14. If still connections drops `factory reset` your `router`

## Environment

###### macOS

```bsh
➜  ~ sw_vers        
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.4
BuildVersion:   20F71

➜  ~ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

###### raspberrypi

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

## Note

- Default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks like this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vsTW49vh)

Comment: What settings did you have in the `~/.ssh/config` file on your Mac?

Comment: I have tried using the IP address instead of the `.local` address - it made no difference. Your comment re "coherent" is a bit ambiguous to me - do you mean that the settings must be the same?... which ones exactly? I appreciate your answer, but your lack of any detail isn't particularly enlightening... IOW - how did you test your solution?

Comment: I'll try this, but I have a question for you first: Is your `local machine` a Mac? Windows? Linux?

Comment: OK, thanks - I really appreciate your effort. I'll try this again, but please note that my question is about the Mac-to-RPi SSH connection - specifically mac os Catalina. It's interesting that the same ver of SSH and LibreSSL is used on Catalina & Mojave.

Comment: My mistake - Big Sur, not Mojave. But your statement that the two environments (Catalina & Big Sur) are `the exact same` is a bit of a stretch - there are more variables due to diffs in the *other software components*. But let's not get distracted - I said I'll try your suggestion, and I will. And **if** that fixes my issue, then your answer will become the "accepted answer"

Comment: I have tried your suggestion - as it applied to my case - and it made no difference. That is to say, I continue to get dropped connections after: **1)** "emptying" `~/.ssh/config` & `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, and **2)** initiating a connection with `ssh pi@<ip address`.

Comment: Diffs: `Banner /etc/issue.net` added.  Still drops connections.

Comment: ?! Gee - why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I apologize - I should have made it clear that my previous comment was sarcastic. Let me try again: It seems to me your approach in this answer is that if I restore everything to *"factory/default"* settings, then it will ***just work*** - as your experience seems to be. I must tell you, with no offense intended, that approach is not helpful to me. I appreciate your effort, but this is going nowhere.