# Raspberry Pi Zero W SSH: `client_loop: send disconnect: broken pipe/timeout/Connection reset`

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, connection

I am using a **Zero W** for Environmental Data Logging.
I am using a 3A rated power supply.
The device itself is exclusively used remotely via ssh or VNC.
For both cases, I am spontaneous losing connection to the device.

On some occasions, the **device froze** while I was using SSH and was hitting Tab (**Autocomplete**), but here I couldn't find a suitable solution for me, the following links didn't solve the problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602518/ssh-connection-client-loop-send-disconnect-broken-pipe-or-connection-reset

so I edited my `~/.ssh/config`, but without solving the issue:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 20
    TCPKeepAlive no
```

I noticed that sometimes I have several **"^@"** before a reboot in my `/var/logs/syslog`, but not always.

```
Dec  9 12:01:01 rasp2 CRON[1041]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/testalive.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec  9 12:02:01 rasp2 CRON[1051]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/testalive.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
Dec  9 12:02:15 rasp2 systemd-modules-load[85]: Inserted module 'dwc2'
Dec  9 12:02:15 rasp2 systemd-modules-load[85]: Inserted module 'g_ether'
Dec  9 12:02:15 rasp2 systemd-modules-load[85]: Inserted module 'i2c_dev'
```

Another point was the **powermanagment**, but it seams not related:
[Make "iw wlan0 set power_save off" permanent](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/make-iw-wlan0-set-power-save-off-permanent)

I have one crontab script running each minute, and I can effectively confirm that the device stops working. The final step is removing power and restart the device.

Is there any idea how I can approach the problem? How to find the issue/ which logfiles to check?

Comment: Not that it will help much, but this issue has been around for a while with no solution AFAIK - see [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111265/what-causes-raspberry-pi-to-reliably-drop-ssh-connections-client-loop-send-di)